# Is SSL Application Data compressed?

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

I use HttpURLConnection to browse to a HTTPS image link. I try to compare the total bytes i read from input stream VS the size of the total Application Data size in the TLS packet (capture with Wireshark). Apparently the size i read from input stream are bigger than the total size of the Application Data in the TLS packet.
So, i was wondering whether data was compressed in the TLS packet. I've tried to do some read up but still not quite sure.

Answer (score 4):

While TLS can compress the traffic it is usually disabled in the stacks for security reasons (see [BREACH attack](http://breachattack.com/) and similar). More likely is that compression inside HTTP is used (i.e. `Content-encoding`). And it is also possible that you just did not look correctly, because usually images are already compressed (at least PNG, GIF, JPEG but not BMP) so further compression is usually not tried or has no noticeable effect.